# Solving multiple PDEs in Fipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pde, fipy

I'm trying to solve a system of partial differential equations in Python, using [Fipy](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/index.html). I have a system of at least 3 PDEs.

I was wondering which approach is best for solving such a system? Fipy supports both [coupled and uncoupled](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.coupled.html) approaches for systems of PDEs. I was wondering, first, if Fipy even supports more than 2 coupled equations, and, if not (or if so), what is the best way of solivng such a system?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, coupled will achieve better convergence than uncoupled. However, the more equations that are coupled, the larger the matrix that must be built, so coupled may require too much memory for particularly large problems.

There is no limit to how many equations may be coupled.

Even when coupling, any non-linear coefficients will still call for [sweeping](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html#iterations-timesteps-and-sweeps-oh-my).